# Extract data from certificate with perl Crypt::X509

Tags: perl, ssl, x509, pem

I'm trying to extract the data from a .pem certificate with the Crypt::X509 library, but I get an error in object construction.
Here is what I'm doing:
1. Read the .pem file's content:

```
my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
   $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat $s_filename;
open FILE, "<$s_filename" or die "no such file";
binmode FILE;
my $pem_cert;
read FILE, $pem_cert, $size;
close FILE;
```

2. Decode the content from base64 to receive the DER formatted content. This is done because the CPAN documentation of the Crypt::X509 library states that it needs to be passed:

> A variable containing the DER formatted certificate to be parsed

```
my $der = MIME::Base64::decode($pem_cert);
```

3. Call the Crypt::X509 constructor and check for errors:

`my $oref_x509= Crypt::X509->new(cert=>$der);
if ( $oref_x509->error ) {
   warn "Error on parsing certificate: ",
   $oref_x509->error;
}`

I get the following error:

```
Error on parsing certificate: decode error 04<=>30 0 8  at ..<path>../Convert/ASN1/_decode.pm line 113.
```

I've tried with other certificate, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting the certificate from PEM to DER using MIME::Base64::decode you need to remove the PEM header and trailer, i.e. instead of decoding

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICVTCCAbegAwIBAgIELwBe7DAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjAaMRgwFgYDVQQDDA9mb28u
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

you should decode only the base64 part:

```
MIICVTCCAbegAwIBAgIELwBe7DAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjAaMRgwFgYDVQQDDA9mb28u
....
```

Since `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` etc contain valid base64 characters they will be used for decoding and the invalid characters silently ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to open a base64 encoded file in binary mode, as it is already 8-bit clean. However a DER file is binary, and so the use of `binmode()` is correct in that instance.

The problem, I think, is that the certificate you are trying to
parse is actually in PEM format and not DER format. If you look at Stephan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38991864/791908), he details the difference (mainly that a DER is the base64 decoded variant of the PEM, after removing the PEM header/footer).

If you have access to openssl, you can convert it from PEM to DER with the command:

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in cert.pem -out cert.der
```

(where `cert.pem` is the name of your input certificate).

You should then be able to use that with Crypt::X509.

If I attempt to parse a PEM format file, or base64 decode it and parse it, I get the same error:

```
Failed to parse cert: decode error 04<=>30 0 8  at /usr/local/share/perl5/Convert/ASN1/_decode.pm line 113.
```

However if I use the DER version, it works correctly:

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use Crypt::X509;

my $file = 'cert.der';
my $size = (stat $file)[7];

my $cert;
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "failed to open cert: $!";
binmode($fh);
read $fh, $cert, $size;
close($fh);

my $x509 = Crypt::X509->new(cert => $cert);
if($x509->error) {
    die "Failed to parse cert: " . $x509->error;
}
```